# Get the error> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro'

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am new to android studio and when I try to Generate Signed Bundle/Apk it shows the error. Please help

Comment: Which error? I see no error in your post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question title is dedicated to summarize your question. It is not the first line of the question. A good question should be understandable without the title.